# Create message in Exchange causes "UnableToDeserializePostBody"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have some code that was working just fine a few months ago, but something in the Graph API has changed and this no longer works. I am trying to create a message in an existing folder, by doing a POST to this url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jjones@transend.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/AAMkADNjAAA=/messages
```

(folder id shortened)

The call fails with http error 400, and the returned error is "UnableToDeserializePostBody". The input json is shown below. By experimentation I was able to trace the problem specifically to "singleValueExtendedProperties". I normally put several properties there, but for this test I removed all but the one you see.  I have tried other properties as well, they all fail.  This seems like some stupid formatting error but I can't see it.  Any help appreciated.

```
{
"subject": "Test again",
"Sender": {
"emailAddress": {
"name": "John Doe",
"address": "missing@domain.com"
}
},
"body": {
"contentType": "TEXT",
"content": "This is a text message."
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"name": "Jane Smith",
"address": "missing@domain.com"
}
}
],
"ccRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"name": "Bob Jones",
"address": "missing@domain.com"
}
}
],
"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
{
"propertyId": "SystemTime 0x0039",
"value": "1998-07-29T21:30:00.0000+00:00"
}
],
"importance": "normal"
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is you are specifying the property('propertyid') in [singleValueExtendedProperties object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) is not valid. There are only 2 properties in singleValueExtendedProperties. One is `id` and the other is `value`.

Replace 'propertyId' with `id`.

I have tested it in POSTMAN with your payload changing the propertyId to id and it worked.

[image]

Request Body:-

```
{
"subject": "Test again",
"Sender": {
"emailAddress": {
"name": "John Doe",
"address": "missing@domain.com"
}
},
"body": {
"contentType": "TEXT",
"content": "This is a text message."
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"name": "Jane Smith",
"address": "missing@domain.com"
}
}
],
"ccRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"name": "Bob Jones",
"address": "missing@domain.com"
}
}
],
"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
{
"id": "SystemTime 0x0039",
"value": "1998-07-29T21:30:00.0000+00:00"
}
],
"importance": "normal"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does appear to work.  I'm pretty sure something must have changed in Graph since I originally worked on this code last summer, but this is fine.

Comment: Struggling trying to test my problem with postman.  Not sure how to get Token prior to testing in Postman

Answer (score 0):

The response (with HTTP status code 400 and content `{"error":{"code":"UnableToDeserializePostBody","message":"were unable to deserialize "}}`) occurs when you set an unexpected `Content-Type` header.
If you set one, it should be `application/json`.